# Is it possible to make an SSIM algorithm in PHP?

Tags: php, image-processing, ssim

Does PHP have enough low-layer methods in order to implement an image comparison metric such as SSIM (structural similarity)?

Do you have an SSIM function for PHP? I've been searching but I can't find it. I will try to make it on my own, by converting code from C.

Thank you!

Comment: You can probably do it with functions from the GD library, but I wouldn't want to do it :-) I'd find a shell command to do it and call it via `exec`.

Comment: You could implement something as a PHP module, but Russell's or Kryten's advice seems the quicker way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [GD](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) it is theoretically possible to do any image processing that you would do in C (albeit probably [rather more slowly](https://dannagle.com/2011/09/benchmarking-c-versus-java-versus-php-programming-languages/)). But what I have done in the past is to just write a simple C program to do the processing, and call it from PHP. This usually requires you to save the image to a temporary file, if it exists only in a database, but it allows you to use your existing C code without porting.

Comment: Thanks! You're totally right, why didn't I think of that before!